# Set DIV height for each by it's data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through over each div that has a class of block and set it's height individually based on it's data-attribute **data-height**

HTML

```
<div class="block" data-height="300"></div>
<div class="block" data-height="500"></div>
<div class="block" data-height="700"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.block').each(function(){ 
    var size = $this.attr('data-height');
    $(this).height(size);
});
```

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/MLnBY/166/

It's not returning the height when I have it in the each method though thus not setting the height for each one.

Comment: `data-*` attributes can be also accessed by doing `.data('height');`.

Comment: @D4V the way OP is doing it is still valid.

Comment: I know, I never said it was invalid. Just pointing that out :)

Comment: $(this).data("height")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `$this`; replace it with `$(this)`

```
var size = $(this).attr('data-height');
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I think $this would have to be a cached/var of $(this) am I correct? in order for it to work that way.

Comment: @Myo $this would be just a variable, unrelated to $(this). You of course can do `$this=$(this)` and then use `$this` wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the () on the second line of JS at $(this)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do it using pure javascript like this:

```
var size = this.getAttribute('data-height');
```